# Aligning .aspx buttons

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an update panel that contains a label, a dropDownList and two buttons:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="dropDownList" style="position:relative;" runat="server">
            <label>
                    Select New File: </label>
                    <div id="ddl" runat="server">
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCaseFiles" DataSourceID="dsMyCaseFiles" DataTextField="Display"
                    DataValueField="FileID" OnPreRender="ddl_PreRender" Width="524px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCaseFiles_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCaseFiles"
                    ToolTip="Casefile Required" InitialValue="-1" Text="*" Display="Dynamic" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ListSearchExtender ID="ddlExtCaseFiles" runat="server" PromptCssClass="ListSearchExtenderPrompt"
                    TargetControlID="ddlCaseFiles" BehaviorID="ddlExtCaseFiles" Enabled="True" />
                    </div>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnMoveCaseFile" runat="server" Text="" 
                   style="float:left;" onclick="btnMoveCaseFile_Click"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
                   style="float:right" onclick="btnCancel_Click"/>
                   <br />
            </div>
                   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
```

I am trying to get my buttons to line up like this:(button at the beginning of the DropDownList and a button at the End)
[image]

I've tried float-absolute etc.

Comment: Have you tried adding a margin to your buttons (left margin for your left button, right for right) to push them in?  I would also suggest seperating all of your inline CSS.

Comment: I set it's position to absolute then margin-left but nothing happens except for it going absolute. I can change the margin but the button just seems to stay in the same spot regardless of the margin amount

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Seems as though you have to add in px after the number.....

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnMoveCaseFile" runat="server" Text="" 
                   style="position:absolute; float:left; margin-left:104px;" onclick="btnMoveCaseFile_Click"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
                   style="position:relative; float:right; margin-right:63px;"
```

since I had margin-right:63; instead of margin-right:63px;

Comment: I thought you had to leave the px out.. but thank you anyways for your help.